# AngularJS: plug spinner into $httpProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a spinner defined in my `ng-app`'s base template. And I have the following code to show/hide it automatically whenever there is an active AJAX request on the way:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    // Request interceptor(s)
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data, headersGetter) {
        window.httpStart();
        return data;
    });

    // Response interceptor(s)
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('spinnerInterceptor');
})

app.factory('spinnerInterceptor', function ($q, $window) {
    return function (promise) {
        // Hide spinner on success.
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            window.httpEnd();
            return response;
        },

        // Hide spinner on failure.
        function (response) {
            window.httpEnd();
            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    };
});

app.config(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (typeof (window.httpQueue) != 'undefined') {
            if (window.httpQueue > 0) {
                angular.element('#ng-loading').show();
            } else {
                angular.element('#ng-loading').hide();
            }
        }
    }, 50);

    /**
     * Mark the start of a new HTTP request.
     */
    window.httpStart = function httpStart() {
        if (typeof (window.httpQueue) == 'undefined') {
            window.httpQueue = 0;
        };

        window.httpQueue++;
    };

    /**
     * Mark the end of a HTTP request.
     */
    window.httpEnd = function httpEnd() {
        if (typeof (window.httpQueue) != 'undefined') {
            window.httpQueue--;
        };
    };
});
```

I hate using `setInterval` here in view of performance, specially because our (corporate) userbase is going to use this on IE8.

Is my concern unfounded? If not, how can I improve this piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to put your helper `httpStart` and `httpEnd` methods on the global window object. Since an interceptor is defined using `.factory()`, it can treated like any other angular factory that has its own functions, with one exception: the recommended method for defining interceptors is to return an object with [specific properties (response/request/requestError/responseError)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).

Interceptor/factory:

```
app.factory('spinnerInterceptor', function($q, $rootScope) {
    // this gets set once, when the interceptor is first requested.
    $rootScope.httpQueue = 0;

    return {
        'request': function(config) {
            $rootScope.httpQueue++;
            return config;
        },
        'response': function(response) {
            $rootScope.httpQueue--;
            return response;
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ng-loading" ng-show="$root.httpQueue > 0"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use store if the ng-loading need to be shown or not in the $rootscope and afterward just using normal angularjs html

```
angular.module('myApp', []).run(function($rootScope) {
     $rootScope.httpQueue = 0;
})

app.config(function ($rootscope) {
window.httpStart = function httpStart() {
    if (typeof ($rootScope.httpQueue) == 'undefined') {
        $rootscope.httpQueue = 0;
    };

    $rootScope.httpQueue++;
};

/**
 * Mark the end of a HTTP request.
 */
window.httpEnd = function httpEnd() {
    if (typeof ($rootScope.httpQueue) != 'undefined') {
        $rootScope.httpQueue--;
    };
};
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="ng-loading" ng-show="$root.httpQueue > 0"/>
```

If you can avoid to use global variable then use controller / service as better approach.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I went with yours + the no global method approach.